# remove html tags from result in CodeIgniter

Tags: resultset, codeigniter-3

I am getting result from database

```
$query = $this->db->query("Select Query");
return $query->result_array();
```

In controller

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
echo json_encode($query);
```

Now I want to remove all html tags from text inside array result in model.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function!